# How do I change the color of dotted lines in an Excel graph?

Tags: excel

In Excel, I want to change color of the dotted lines in a "Line with Markers" graph.

I clicked to format the legend and I chose a color in Border and it changed the color of the line only, and not the markers. How do I change both the line and markers color?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the markers and not on the line. proceed with the same steps as with the line.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the line (in the graph) and select `Format Data Series`. You'll get something looking like this (might differ depending on your version):

[image]

Here you can choose Marker Line Colour, Marker Shape (in "Marker Options"), Marker Inner colour (in "Marker Fill") and many other things. Hope that helps!